# Show that $\bar A = A \cup [(0,0), (0,1)]$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

In $(\mathbb R^2, ||\cdot||_{\infty})$, let:

$A_0 = ]0,1] \times \{0\}$

$A_n = [(\frac{1}{n}, 0), (\frac{1}{n}, 1)]$ for each $n \ge 1$.

$A = \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n$

It is required to prove that:

$\bar A = A \cup [(0,0), (0,1)]$

I proved that $A \cup [(0,0), (0,1)]$ is contained in $\bar A$.

For the other inclusion, I should probably take a sequence in $A$ and prove that its limit is either in $A$ or in that segment. I did a proof on scratch, but it lacks rigour, and after many attempts, I had no luck constructing a rigorous proof. Hence I am asking for a rigorous proof for that, not a hint, because I already know what is going on.

Though, any other suitable approaches are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What does this mean: $ [(0,0), (0,1)]$?

Comment: @zoli, the segment connecting these two points.

Comment: Why you don't just prove that the complement of A∪[(0,0),(0,1)] is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

So, this is how I picture your sets:

[image]

and I added my $B_y$.

For any $y$:

$$B_y=\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{(\frac{1}{n},y)\}}={\{(0,y)\}\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{(\frac{1}{n},y)\}}.$$

Then $$\overline A=\bigcup_{y\in[0,1]}B_y\cup\overline A_0={\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{(\frac{1}{n},y)\} }\cup A_0\cup \{(0,0)\}\cup [(0,0), (0,1)]=$$=
$$={\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n }\cup [(0,0), (0,1)]=A\cup[(0,0), (0,1)] .$$

since $$\overline A_0=A_0\cup\{(0,0)\}.$$

As far as the inclusion question see the following cases.
$$x=\begin {cases}
(\frac{1}{n},y)& \text { for some } n \text { and for some y}\in [0,1],& \text { (case } \alpha)\text{ or}\\
(0,\ y)&\text { for some y}\in ]0,1], &\text { (case } \beta) \text{ or}& \\
(x,\ 0)&\text { for some y}\in [0,1], x\in \ ]0,1] &\text { (case }\gamma)\text{ or}\\
(0,\ 0)&\ &\text { (case } \delta).
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: After second thoughts, I am not quite sure how this proves the other inclusion. I think I misunderstood what went on. Would you mind elaborating a little bit? Thanks.

Comment: You are right. I'll have to go on ...

Comment: Am I right if I think that $]0,1]\times \{0\}=\{x,y: y=0, x\in (0,1]\}?$

Comment: Sure, that's correct.

Comment: Is this still true: $\overline {]0,1]\times \{0\}}=[0,1]\times \{0\}$ ?

Comment: Yes. Are you thinking about adding $(y,0)$ to $B_y$?

Comment: Just to make sure that we understand each other I drew a little picture...

Comment: The first picture is the correct one. I understood the role of the $B_y$'s, but I can't link that to what is required: $\bar A \subset A \cup ([(0,0),(0,1)]$.

Comment: I cannot do it any better.

Comment: In general, you have $\cup_y\overline {C_y}\subset \overline{\cup_y C_y}$, with $C_y=\cup_n{(1/n,y)}$ so why $$\overline A=\cup_y B_y\cup\overline{A_0}?$$

Comment: @san:
 
$C_y=\{(1,y),\cdots (\frac{1}{n},y), \cdots\}$;

$\overline {C_y}=\{(0,y)\}\cup \{(1,y),\cdots\, (\frac{1}{n},y), \cdots\};$

$\bigcup_{y\in[0,1]}\overline {C_y}=\bigcup_{y\in[0,1]}\{(0,y)\}\cup\bigcup_{y\in[0,1]}\{(1,y),\cdots\, (\frac{1}{n},y), \cdots\}=[(0,0),(0,1)]\cup \bigcup_{y\in[0,1]C_y};$

$\bigcup_{y\in[0,1]}C_y=\{[(1,0),(1,1)],\cdots[(\frac{1}{2},0),(\frac{1}{2},1)],\cdots\}$;

$\overline{\bigcup_{y\in[0,1]} {C_y}}=[(0,0),(0,1)]\cup \bigcup_{y\in[0,1]C_y}.$

So, $\bigcup_{y\in[0,1]}\overline {C_y}=\overline{\bigcup_{y\in[0,1]} {C_y}}.$

Comment: This third line of your comment is exactly what you should prove. You are using the final result, so this seems a circular argument to me.

Comment: Give me a little time to think this over (and over) again.

Comment: Why you don't just prove that the complement of $A\cup[(0,0),(0,1)]$ is open?

Comment: OK, OK. Pls. I have (unfortunately) a job... It is not that I don't want to answer or to think about this. Simply, simply I am overtasked.

Comment: Dear @San, The third line contains two statements. Which one of them do you think I should further discuss? Both, perhaps?

Comment: @zoli Your proof is not fixable, since the nice argument of interchanging the unions only shows one inclusion (already proven by the OP). If you want to do things right, you have to prove:                1. Every point with a distance $\varepsilon>0$ to $A\cup[(0,0),(0,1)]$ is not in the closure.        2. Every point which is not in $A\cup[(0,0),(0,1)]$, has a distance $\varepsilon>0$ to $A\cup[(0,0),(0,1)]$ (you have to consider various cases).      This is enough.